# Facebook Share with Mood

Tags: facebook, share, social-networking

I've added a HTML Link for sharing Content, passing my own contents. Is it possible to set a mood? [image: Facebook Mood Sample Screenshot]
It should stay HTML only, no JS.

I'd expect something like "&mood=reading" param.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1111111111111111&display=popup&message=test&summary=test2&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&description=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&picture=https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150&name=myName&caption=my%20fancy%20caption&redirect_uri=google.de&mood=reading" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
```

All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've added a HTML Link for sharing Content, passing my own contents. Is it possible to set a mood?

No, that is not possible using the Feed dialog - but the Share dialog seems to offer that, at least according to the screenshot in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

But be aware, the *only* parameter the Share dialog takes, is the URL to share - everything else is taken from the OG meta tags that URL responds with.

> I'd expect something like "&mood=reading" param.

Users have to select the mood themselves, you can not specify it form them.

(And the same is true for the `message` parameter you tried to pass in your Feed dialog call - it will simply be ignored. Whatever way of sharing/posting you choose, you are *not allowed* to specify the message part for the user, they have to type it in themselves.)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe - too bad this won't work. The site I am working at won't let me use JS.... Thank you anyways for the quick answer!

Comment: You don’t need JS, you can call the Share dialog via URL as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect

Comment: jap, you're right. Sorry, the correct answer would be: As I'm working on an order confirm page on an ecommerce site, i can not use the meta tags and or the URL the sharing user sees right now (as no other user could ever open his OCP). So I could only use the feed dialog or JS as far as I see.